# how to replicate numpy array as a whole

Tags: python, numpy

How can I replicate `numpy` array, so that it would be repeated (as a whole array) n times?

So with an example array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0, 5)
```

I want to create an array like below, without a need of manually typing `np.arange(0, 5)` n times:

```
x_3times = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 5), np.arange(0, 5), np.arange(0, 5)])
```

or with a set length of output (e.g. 12)?

```
x_12 = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 5), np.arange(0, 5), np.arange(0, 5)])[0:12]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).

```py
>> x_3times = np.tile(x, 3)
>> x_3times

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

For repeating till some particular limit, use [np.resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html)

```py
>> x_12 = np.resize(x, 12)
>> x_12

array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question for some extension - is there any method for that? (other than slicing) after `np.tile`

Answer (score 2):

Simply try list comprehension:

```py
x_3times = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 5) for x in range(3)])
```

where the number `3` can be substituted by any number `n`.

**edit**

if you want to limit the length by any number, you can simply do:

```py
cutoff = 12
x_3times = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 5) for x in range(3)])[:cutoff]
```

which will result to:

```py
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
```

However, this isn't a very efficient line of code, especially when dealing with large numbers. Another answer would probably be to make a generator:

```py
def generator(arr, n, cutoff=None):
    length = len(arr)
    if cutoff:
        for i in range(cutoff):
            yield arr[i%length]
    else:
        for _ in range(n):
            for i in arr:
                yield i

array = np.array([x for x in generator(np.arange(0, 5), 3, 12)])
```

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question for some extension - is there any method for that? (other than slicing) after creating `x_3times`